# Azure- User cost

Tags: azure

I am trying to calculate the cost per user while hosting on Azure. Lets say one users spends a total of one hour on website a month. I am trying to calculate the hosting costs as the business scales. If there are 10,000 users that I want to provide quality service speeds to, what is a rough estimate of service fees with Azure.

Note: I understand there are a lot of variables but a rough estimate is all that is needed in my forecast.

Comment: What sort of hosting are you using? Web Roles or VM's? Database or no database? How many instances do you want? Maybe try http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ to give you an idea of monthly costs and then divide it by 10,000 users

Comment: I just need an average for one user. What is a ball park; I do know what to expect one user to use or how many instances I need.

Comment: If I knew how much one user would be useing I would not be asking the question. I am not in networking and have no idea how to make appropriate estimates with the calculator.

Comment: You have no idea how much one user would be using but you want an estimate for 10,000 users.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is the same question as here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/cd2c9d78-f01b-402a-8c3a-782e00dafeb9. I answered over there... copying here verbatim:

> You're asking "How long is a string?" No one can answer with the
>   information you've provided.
>
> For example, if you're delivering static, cached content to each user,
>   one server would be more than sufficient to serve 1000 users. If,
>   however, when each user visits the page, you factor the product of two
>   very large prime numbers, a data center wouldn't be enough.
>
> To try to answer the impossible question: 1000 users each spending an
>   hour per month on a site is unlikely to need anything more than a free
>   Web Site (or two extra small instances of a web role in a Cloud
>   Service), so I'd be surprised if your compute costs exceeded $100.
>
> Bandwidth is another potentially significant cost... again, if each
>   user looks at some text versus each user watching an hour-long HD
>   video, this cost could vary by many orders of magnitude. No one can
>   guess for you.